# Can't link to an index.html that is in one level up

Tags: php, html, css, windows, server

This is the structure of my messy host root folder; which I'm hoping to clean up soon;

root (folder)

.....AllWebsites (folder)

.......Website1 (folder)

index.html//please note that these html files below are not in their own folder. So they're sitting in the website1 folder loosely;

index2.html

index3.html

numerous numerous other html files

phpFolder (folder)

..........index.php (file)//this is my landing page

website2 (folder)
and more folders for other websites

So I simply want a button on my index.php called "Second Landing Page"  to link to index.html. So I tried writing;

```
<li><a href='/website1/index.html'><strong>Second Landing Page</strong></a></li>
```

But I get the 404 error. Then I tried writing;

```
href='/allWebsites/website1/index.html

 href='//website1/index.html
```

//I was hoping 2 slashes would bump me up one level but didn't work and many other variations without any luck. This is probably a very simple question but not for me learning as I code these sites.

One way to fix this problem would be to just place a new folder in the phpFolder called htmlFolder and paste all the html files including index.html. Then I would simply write;

```
<li><a href='/htmlFolder/index.html'><strong>Second Landing Page</strong></a></li>
```

But this will be a nightmare, so I'd appreciate any help to simply figure out how to link to the index.html where it currently resides > in the folder above phpFolder named website1 folder.

Comment: Add ../ for each level you want to go up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you're looking for is "relative path".

Taken from http://www.boogiejack.com/server_paths.html

[image: Relative paths]

Comment: Thanks for the link, and I actually by luck did try this; ../website1/index.html because that's where the index.html is, but for some odd reason nothing is working.

Comment: The above table is definitely correct and works. Can you maybe edit your question with a clearer view of where the files are and which ones you're trying to link? I'm confused as to where each file is making it hard for me to provide more direct assistance.

Comment: It was a problem on my end. I need to redo the code but your answer was correct it's just that it won't work unless I redo everything. Thanks